# how can pass variable id to form action in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have following form to update category data

```
<h1>{{isset($image)?'Edit':'New'}}  Category</h1>

            <hr/>
            @if(isset($image))
    <form method="PUT" action="http://localhost:8000/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
```

now I need pass $image-> id to the action

```
 action="http://localhost:8000/update/ image->id here
```

how can I do this?

Comment: You mean to pass data into url ? Then : `http://localhost:8000/update/?image=id`

Comment: it is not sucess

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/update/{{$image->id}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
<form method="PUT" action="http://localhost:8000/update/{{$image->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Assuming that you are using resource controller, with `update` function similar to:

```
public function update($request, $id)
```

Comment: what if i am using something like this `action('PostController@store')`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using action method like this `action('PostController@store')`

so you can use this to call the **id** or any **varible**

```
`<form method="POST" action="{{action('PostController@update',[$image->id])}}">`
```